# stat_bin requires the following missing aesthetics: x

Tags: shiny

I created the following shiny app and try to plot a histogram using the `input$name` variable as one of the parameter, but the compiler said there is an error

> `"stat_bin requires the following missing aesthetics: x"`

It seems like the value of `input$name` is not able to be plugged into variable x

P.S.  Do not need to care about `tdata` since it stores the data from one of my `.csv` files

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Demonstation of textInput widget in shiny"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel("Enter the personal information",
                 textInput("name", " Enter your name please", ""),
                 textInput("age", "Enter your age", "")), 
    mainPanel(("Personal Information"), 
              textOutput("myname"),
              textOutput("myage"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$myname <- renderText(input$name)
  output$myage <- renderText(input$age)
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


renderPlot(
  ggplot(tdata, aes_string(x=input$name)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=5) + 
  theme_classic() 

)
```

Comment: Try putting `renderPlot` inside `server`. The way you coded it, it seems all inputs from the app started with `shinyApp` are out of scope for the `renderPlot`.